# error: 'atomic_t' was not declared in this scope And others for other

Tags: opencl

Please Help...
In opencl program i am getting these errors.
I dont have "oclUtils.h" header file. S0 I haven't included it in my program. Is this the reason why I am getting this problem. I am also sending my kernel.
And if this is the reason, how can I use atomic function without using oclUtils.h?

```
*"__kernel void BLAS_susdot_kernel(__global float *x,__global int *index,__global float        *y,const int n,__global float* dot_p)                    \n" \
"{                                                                                      \n" \
"    int block_x = get_group_id(0);                                                                     \n" \
"    int thread_x = get_local_id(0);                                                                    \n" \
"    int i = get_global_id(0);                                                                          \n" \
"    float dot_value, old = *dot_p;                                                                     \n" \
"    int warp_thread_id = i & (32-1);                                                                   \n" \
"    __local float tmp[512];                                                                                    \n" \
"    __local float share_dot_p;                                                                         \n" \
"    if(thread_x == 0)                          \n" \
"       share_dot_p = 0.0;                              \n" \
"    if (i < n)                                 \n" \
"   {                                        \n" \
"        tmp[i]= x[i]*y[index[i]];           \n" \
"        if(warp_thread_id <16 && (i+16)< n) \n" \
"            tmp[i]+=tmp[i+16];              \n" \
"        if(warp_thread_id <8 && (i+8)< n )  \n" \
"            tmp[i]+=tmp[i+8];               \n" \
"        if(warp_thread_id <4 && (i+4)< n )  \n" \
"            tmp[i]+=tmp[i+4];               \n" \
"        if(warp_thread_id <2 && (i+2)< n)   \n" \
"            tmp[i]+=tmp[i+2];               \n" \
"        if(warp_thread_id==0 && (i+1)< n)   \n" \
"        {                                   \n" \
"            tmp[i]+=tmp[i+1];               \n" \
"            do                              \n" \
"            {                               \n" \
"                dot_value = old;            \n" \
"                old = convert_int( atomic_cmpxchg((volatile __global unsigned int*)&share_dot_p, convert_int(dot_value), convert_int(tmp[i] + dot_value)));  \n" \
"            } while (dot_value != old);     \n" \
"            //share_dot_p +=tmp[i];         \n" \
"        }                                   \n" \
"        if(thread_x==0)                  \n" \
"        {                                   \n" \
"                                            \n" \
"            do                              \n" \
"            {                               \n" \
"                dot_value = old;            \n" \
"                old = convert_int(atomic_cmpxchg((volatile __global unsigned int *) dot_p, convert_int(dot_value), convert_int(share_dot_p+dot_value)));  \n" \
"            } while(dot_value != old);                                                 \n" \
"               // *dot_p += share_dot_p;                                               \n" \
"                                                                                       \n" \
"        }                                                                              \n" \
"   }                                                                                   \n" \
"}                                                                                      \n" \
"\n";*
```

**Error I am getting:**

```
Build Program Info: ptxas application ptx input, line 160; error   : Label expected for argument 0 of instruction 'call'
ptxas application ptx input, line 160; error   : Call target not recognized
ptxas application ptx input, line 160; error   : Function 'atomic_cmpxchg' not declared in this scope
ptxas application ptx input, line 160; error   : Call target not recognized
ptxas application ptx input, line 185; error   : Label expected for argument 0 of instruction 'call'
ptxas application ptx input, line 185; error   : Call target not recognized
ptxas application ptx input, line 185; error   : Function 'atomic_cmpxchg' not declared in this scope
ptxas application ptx input, line 185; error   : Call target not recognized
ptxas application ptx input, line 161; error   : Unknown symbol 'atomic_cmpxchg'
ptxas application ptx input, line 186; error   : Unknown symbol 'atomic_cmpxchg'
ptxas fatal   : Ptx assembly aborted due to errors
error   : Ptx compilation failed: gpu='sm_13', device code='cuModuleLoadDataEx_4'
: Considering profile 'compute_13' for gpu='sm_13' in 'cuModuleLoadDataEx_4'
: Retrieving binary for 'cuModuleLoadDataEx_4', for gpu='sm_13', usage mode='  '
: Considering profile 'compute_13' for gpu='sm_13' in 'cuModuleLoadDataEx_4'
: Control flags for 'cuModuleLoadDataEx_4' disable search path
: Ptx binary found for 'cuModuleLoadDataEx_4', architecture='compute_13'
: Ptx compilation for 'cuModuleLoadDataEx_4', for gpu='sm_13', ocg options='  '
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `atomic_cmpxchg`, which is a part of an optional extension in OpenCL, you need to check that your device supports it, and then enable it in your kernel code:

1. Check that `cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics` is listed in the extensions returned by `clGetDeviceInfo(..., CL_DEVICE_EXTENSIONS, ...)`
2. Add the following to the top of your kernel code:

`#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics : enable`

Note that if you are using atomic functions with __local or 64-bit operands, you may need to enable additional extensions:

```
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics : enable
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics : enable
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_int64_base_atomics : enable
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics : enable
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics : enable
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_int64_extended_atomics : enable
```

Additionally, make sure you are using OpenCL 1.1 or higher, since the atomic functions were named differently in OpenCL 1.0. For example if you are compiling your kernel offline using NVidia's `nvcc` utility, make sure you are specifying the `-arch` command line switch.

These particular errors are unrelated to oclUtils.h. That is an NVidia header file that you should only need if you are invoking ocl* functions in your host (not kernel) code.